# MVC3, Scaffolding a Controller, available selections from Model drop-down

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I have a MVC3 project that is referencing a WCF web service....and that WCF service references a data class library.

When I try to scaffold a controller, I have the option to select a Model class from a drop-down.

I would expect to see the data classes that are defined in my data class library, but they're are none there.  I'm puzzled by this.  I thought that because the MVC project is referencing a WCF service that is referencing the data class library that the classes would be available to choose from.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the WCF service expose the types in the data class library in its  API?

Answer (score 0):

I had what sounds like the same problem. Take a look at this answer and verify you don't have the exact same thing happening [Attempting to add a strongly typed view does not find any classes in the MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773774/attempting-to-add-a-strongly-typed-view-does-not-find-any-classes-in-the-mvc-pro)