# ASP.net MVC strongly typed view dropdownlist is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sitecore

For a Sitecore7 solution I setup an ASP.net MVC3 project. I'm trying to add a new view to my controller action using the "Add view" wizard, by clicking right on the View() code > Add view.

```
public class HomeController : SitecoreController
{
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The "Add view" wizard shows up, but when I checked the checkbox "Create a strongly-typed view" the Model class dropdownlist is empty.

There are no build errors. However I cleaned, build and rebuild the solution, but that doesn't fix the problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and the enviroment is completely updated.
I searched the internet and found this simular looking [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773774/attempting-to-add-a-strongly-typed-view-does-not-find-any-classes-in-the-mvc-pro), but the solution doesn't fix the problem.

I have tried to fix it in a day, without success. Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Comment: Can't you just type in the name of your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.FIRST YOU DELETE ALL FILES IN YOUR APPLICATION BIN FOLDER.THEN TRY BUILD THE APPLICATION. OR
2.DO THE FIRST STEP AND IF YOU ARE USING EF TRY TO UPDATE YOUR DATABASE BY TYPING "update-database" from your package manager console

Comment: 1. Tried, but doesn't work. 2. Gives this message: No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Website'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration). Keep in mind that it's an Sitecore MVC project, there is no linked database in this project.

Answer (score 3):

You can just type in the model at the top of your view, like this:

```
@model your.namespace.goes.here
```

Comment: I want to use the Add view wizard to generate my views. That's much faster then creating manual all views.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add a strongly-typed View is:

right click your Views folder -> Add -> Scaffold item -> MVC view

From there you can select whatever model and type you have available in the project. However, keep in mind that old MVC templates (like MVC 3) might not have all options available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot find the Scaffold item.